# Django: cannot add foreight key to User

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-migrations

I am using ldap to do authentication, just like [Understanding Django-LDAP authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940466/understanding-django-ldap-authentication).

My model is:

```
class MyFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

But I cannot make migrations:

```
python src/manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to myfile without a default;
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

Then I input datetime.date.today() and run python manage.py migrate
The error is:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 915, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'
```

Any idea? Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='MyFile',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('file', models.FileField(upload_to='files')),
            ('slug', models.SlugField(blank=True)),
            ('user', models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field fileupload.MyFile.user: auth.User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a *default User ID for all the existing files*. It has to be an existing User ID and an *integer*. It cannot be a `datetime.date`.

Or, if applicable, you can make the File->User link *optional*:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field fileupload.MyFile.user: auth.User