# Django Authentication Ldap Full example

Tags: django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I partially understood the Django Ldap Authentication. Can anyone give the full example developing very basic application that uses **Django Authentication Ldap** .

I went through this [resource](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html) and tried to understand many things but still I am not able to understand that how to use it in implementation. How to create user model that will be used along with LdapBackend class, and how
to write many stuff within authenticate() method etc.

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://fle.github.io/combine-ldap-and-classical-authentication-in-django.html) you can see a full example very well guided showing how to create a custom `LDAPBackend`.

You need to configure your LDAP settings in `settings.py` (as shown in the link you posted) and add your `LDAPBackend` to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`. You can use the default LDAPBackend provided or create a custom one and use that.

Using the default `LDAPBackend` provided by `django-auth-ldap`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Using a custom `LDAPBackend` if you need to add extra logic to the authentication:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'accounts.backends.MyLDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Then in `accounts/backends.py`:

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend

class MyLDAPBackend(LDAPBackend):
    """ A custom LDAP authentication backend """

    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        """ Overrides LDAPBackend.authenticate to add custom logic """

        user = LDAPBackend().authenticate(self, username, password)

        """ Add custom logic here """

        return user
```

Check the example linked above for more details.

If you are new to LDAP I would recommend to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19944581/9848469) (and the other one as well) in another question regarding this topic.

---

UPDATE FOR NEWER VERSIONS OF [django-auth-ldap](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custombehavior.html)

Thanks @wolf2600 for pointing out that now instead of `authenticate` you'll need to override `authenticate_ldap_user` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Of note:  The syntax for django_auth_ldap has changed.  Intead of overriding `authenticate` you'll need to override `authenticate_ldap_user`

https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custombehavior.html

```
    def authenticate_ldap_user(self, username, password):
        """ Overrides LDAPBackend.authenticate to save user password in django """
        user = LDAPBackend.authenticate_ldap_user(self, username, password)

        # If user has successfully logged in, save password in django database
        if user:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

        return user
```

I was kicking myself for hours (cough***days***cough) wondering why my custom `authenticate` wasn't being called until I found that readthedocs.io page.